# Notation for the "calculus of variations derivative"?

Tags: soft-question, calculus-of-variations

I am tired of writing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial q} - \frac d {dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot q}$ many times, especially when my $f$ is actually a more complex expression. I have taken to writing this as $\Theta(f)$ in my own notes, but I am doing a project which will be presented to other people and I want to know if there's any precedent for notation for this. I have searched and found nothing: the closest I have found was the usual $\delta$-notation for the functional derivative of a functional, but I am searching for this specific operator.

So, is there any pre-existing notation for $f \mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} - \frac d {dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot q}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this specific operator". This is precisely just a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), with a common notation being $\delta F/\delta q$, where $F$ is the corresponding action. Sometimes, and especially in the physics literature, the notation $E[q]$ is also used with $E$ representing "equations of motion".

Comment: @EuYu Yes. I don't want to talk about the action, though, or add any new, superfluous names.
Can I write $\delta f/\delta q$ or $f[q]$ to mean the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial q} - \frac d {dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot q}$? If so, then this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EuYu's comment is sufficient and correct. Once you define $\delta$ as the functional differential, you can write $\delta F/\delta q$, or $F_q$ where it is unambiguous to do so. This essentially represents the Gâteaux derivative.

The notation $\delta f/\delta q$ in your comment does not make sense, as $f$ is a function so its domain cannot be a manifold.

If you do not want to introduce $F$ in your notation, I would go for what you have done, or rewrite the expression as $f_q-(f_{\dot q})'$ for simplicity (again where it is unambiguous). Otherwise there is no standard notation for the LHS of the Euler-Lagrange equation.